# How to develop sense of humor/wit as non-native speaker?

Tags: phrase-usage, slang, jokes

As in topic, I'm advanced in English, I'm looking for simple tricks how to smoothly extricate oneself from situations like awkward silence, when starting conversation with a stranger fails or being misunderstood etc. and I plan to use humor/wit.

I'm already learning idioms and I use them daily, some local(Glasgow/scottish) slang(it's probably interesting to hear a foreign using local slang), watching comedy movies and listen to some comedy podcasts from bbc, but I’m still looking for new ideas.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd say you are on the right track with idioms, since you need extensive vocabulary, knowledge of usage and idioms to make a good pun/word play. Such as [this one](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/224/how-does-the-dalai-lama-walks-into-a-pizza-shop-joke-work?s=1|2.0241). As for the sense of humour that's more an inherent individual characteristic, IMO

Comment: You could also consider miming. https://www.google.com/search?q=miming&num=20&newwindow=1&es_sm=93&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=gSE-VeShD4nksAS2qICoAQ&ved=0CAgQ_AUoAg&biw=1357&bih=900

Comment: Native speakers pick such idioms and humor as they grow up. You can also do so by exposing yourself to comic media in English: movies, series, and books. You will find some of them so amusing that your humor inventory will grow steadily. Personally, I enjoy the witty, sharp, well-built humor of Game of Thrones books. I think that those books are a banquet for highly advanced or nearly native level English speakers.

Comment: What exactly are you looking for in an answer here? I definitely agree that watching English-language media intended to be humorous is probably your best bet. I would suggest stand-up comedy.

Comment: Laughing slightly yourself will cue the listener even if they don't quite understand or appreciate the joke.

Comment: @Dylan Cross + for pointing out the nonverbal aspects of humor.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a question about learning the English language, but rather about being socially confident.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a question about social graces, not language.